# How does filter using or/|| works together?

Tags: javascript

I know how `filter` function works but this my first time encountering the use of filter in this way can someone explain to me how the `isLost: true` objects are the only one being printed with the use of

`!filtered || guest.isLost` ?

```js
const filtered=true

const users = [
  { name: "Jack", isLost: true },
  { name: "Sawyer", isLost: true },
  { name: "Lupin", isLost: false }
];

const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => !filtered || user.isLost).map(user => user)

console.log(filteredUsers)
```

console:

```
[{"name":"Jack","isLost":true},{"name":"Sawyer","isLost":true}]
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: `.map(user => user)` is a no-op.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. If the callback returns true or a [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value for an item in the array, that values is retained in the output array. `!filtered || user.isLost` is only true for the first 2 items in the array.

Comment: @axiac not exactly, not a no-op. `array.map(value => value)` is equivalent to `array.slice()`. But here it is pointless, because `filter()` already returns a new array. So another `slice` only creates garbage for the GC.

Comment: @Thomas as you mentioned, in this context `.map(value => value)` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expr1 || epxr2` returns `expr1`  if it can be evaluate to true, else it returns `expr2`

In your case, as `filtered` is true (then `!filtered` is false), the filter works with the value of `user.isLost`

Answer (score 1):

`!filterd` is always false. So your condition is only true if isLost is true

If you want to filter out everything that has the property isLost:true
Use this condition
`!user.isLost`

```js
const users = [
  { name: "Jack", isLost: true },
  { name: "Sawyer", isLost: true },
  { name: "Lupin", isLost: false }
];

const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => !user.isLost)

console.log(filteredUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

`filtered` is initialized with `true` and never modified.
Consequently, `! filtered` is always `false` and `false || x` is the same as `x`.
And that means the filter condition is `user.isLost`.

Because `.map(user => user)` does not have any effect, your code has the same effect as:

```js
const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => user.isLost)
```